# number of employees on hr.employee on odoo

Tags: python, odoo

**I want to have the number of employees in odoo who are active**, in other words the number of employees who are in the hr.employee list view, this function return me nbr-employee = 0, since 4 days i cant resolve it.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'

    nbr_employee = fields.Integer(compute="_get_count_employee", store='True')

    @api.one
    def _get_count_employee(self):
        for t in self:
            t.nbr_employee = t.env['hr.employee'].sudo().search_count([('active', '=', True)])

 <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook" position="inside">
                    <page string="Indicateurs de performance de recrutement">
                                   <group>
                                       <field name="nbr_employee" string="nbr_employee:"/>
                                    </group>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
            </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hinda ABASSI

You have `store` the field but on the computation not use the field which `depends` to perform the calculation.

```
nbr_employee = fields.Integer(compute="_get_count_employee")

@api.multi
def _get_count_employee(self):
    for emp in self:
        emp.nbr_employee = self.env['hr.employee'].search_count([('active', '=', True)])
```

Also on the `Fields` declaration, you did a mistake use `store=True`.